# Change css for <p> tag in wordpress admin

Tags: admin-css

I am editing the Wordpress back-end with CSS through a plugin called "Admin CSS". I can edit almost anything, but not the height of the `<p>` tag. Right now, the height of the `<p>` tags is to big (please note, the `<p>` tags in admin backend is created when hitting enter (which creates a `&nbsp;` in WordPress code but a `<p>` when checking with inspector).

When I check the code with inspector in chrome, the CSS changes I made for the `<p>` tag is not there. It only shows styling from user agent.

What can I do to change the `<p>` style? Any src code I can change?

Here is all the styles I have tried (I also tried them all with use of `!important` and tried to change `auto` to `0` and `unset` without any luck):

```
p {
    margin: auto;
}

body#tinymce p {
    margin: auto;
}

#tinymce p {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to change the styles of the wysiwyg editor, which I assume you are based on your code example, you need to use the [`add_editor_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_editor_style/) function.

As per the example in the code reference.

**Step 1**

> Add the following to the functions.php file of your theme.

```
/**
 * Registers an editor stylesheet for the theme.
 */
function wpdocs_theme_add_editor_styles() {
    add_editor_style( 'custom-editor-style.css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpdocs_theme_add_editor_styles' );
```

**NB** The stylesheet is relative to theme root.

**Step 2**

> Next, create a file named custom-editor-style.css in your themes root
>   directory. Any CSS rules added to that file will be reflected within
>   the TinyMCE visual editor. The contents of the file might look like
>   this:

```
#tinymce p {
    margin: auto;
}
```

For other `p` tags you could try placing some inline style to the [`admin_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_head). Like so,

```
// Add inline CSS in the admin head with the style tag
// put this in to your theme's functions.php
function my_custom_admin_head() {
    echo '<style>p {margin: auto;}</style>';
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'my_custom_admin_head' );
```

**NB** Also make sure the css selectors are correct. I didn't check them for these examples.

Comment: Do you really need step 1? If you just put that CSS in the 'additional CSS' of your theme, then you should be good. I believe.

Comment: @RickHellewell Additional CSS does not get added to the editor.

Comment: This worked perfect! Thank you so much.